# mysql table is not displaying

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have one database name - manaskavya. In this database I had created 10 table with xampp server. Due to some reason i installed Wamp server in that it was showing only 9 table, It misses one table name 'manas_likes'. Then I again installed the Xampp server but the missing table is not displaying, and when i am creating the new table with same name its, showing table exists, and when I am trying to drop it,repair it or truncate it, its showing table not exists.

I don't know why its happening , if you know please help me out.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Once i faced the same problem. I tried Change table name in the create table query, exequte it and then rename the table. Then drop the table and recreate it.

Comment: did you get the solution then ?? 
I tried this thing also but its showing the same problem means
table doesn't exist..

Comment: sometimes dropping your database recreating it and restarted mysql service

Answer (score 0):

After checking all these details I got some thing, I am right or wrong don't know but it worked for me..
1. When we create new table in database, its create one file with **.frm** extension
you can check this file in **C:\xampp\mysql\data\database_name\anytable.frm**
for wamp **C:\xampp\bin\mysql\mysql5.0.2\data\database_name\anytable.frm** .
2. After inserting data in this particular table it creates two more files with extension
**.MYD** and **.MYI** .
3.

  when we create the backup of the particular database..
- If you are making backup with **phpmyadmin** then such type of problem will never be happen.
- if you are making backup directly from folder means **C:\xampp\mysql\data\database_name** then some time it misses the **.MYD** and **.MYI** extensions files

4. After importing again in database there would be only **.frm** extension file, Due to absence of **.MYD** and **.MYI** extension file it becomes invisible. and it also won't allow you to create new table with same name because **.frm** extension file is already present in your database.
5. So in such type of case go to directly at folder position and delete that specific **.frm** extension file (*Please be sure to delete the correct file*).
6. Then after you will be able to create the table with same name.